# How to extend the sides of cube file in cubegen along with medium resolution?

Tags: density-functional-theory, from-chem-se

I am able to [generate cube](https://gaussian.com/cubegen/) file with (-3) medium resolution. But the map is cutoff at < -7.71 or >7.71.  To extend the cube coverage, I tried to set 120 points per side, but output cubefile has min and max remains  at -7.71 and 7.71, because resolution is higher than medium.

It looks like the program also can read the cube specification from the input stream or from a second cube file. So I tried to type in numbers based the four line format, it gives error.

Any step-by-step codes would be great help!

**cubegen 8 fdensity=mp2 Ar.fchk Ar.cube 120**         min and max coordinates in cube file did not extend...

**cubegen 8 fdensity=mp2 Ar.fchk Ar.cube -1**          hit enter, prompt for input, then I typed in:

```
   1   -10.00000   -10.00000   -10.00000
 120    0.166667    0.000000    0.000000
 120    0.000000    0.166667    0.000000
 120    0.000000    0.000000    0.166667
```

no cube file generated.

Comment: As you've found, the resolution only affects the number of points / spacing, not the origin and limits of the cube. I haven't specified custom cubes before, but I think you want -1 on the first line: "IFlag is the output unit number. If IFlag is less than 0, then a formatted file will be produced; otherwise, an unformatted file will be written." I'm pretty sure "output unit number" is a Fortran phrase. Try "-6" which should write to standard output.